# how to prevent error on using optional property from one of types

Tags: typescript

Typescript linter wants to see property `children` in all of types which returned by `transform`.
How I can fix it when I already write check `prop || []`

```js
interface NestedItem{
  children?: NestedItem[]
}
function buildTree<Item, TransformedItem extends NestedItem>(
  data: Item[],
  transform: (item: Item) => TransformedItem | Item = item => item
) {
  const result = []
  for (const item of data) {
    const transformedItem = transform({...item})
    const resultItem = Object.assign({}, transformedItem, {
      children: transformedItem.children || [] // TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Item | TransformedItem'. Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Item'.
    })
    result.push(resultItem)
  }
  
  return result
}
```

Comment: I think right way is remove returned type `Item` from `transform` function.  
`transform: (item: Item) => TransformedItem = item => item`  
But it generates another error   
  ---
Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'TransformedItem'. 'Item' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TransformedItem', but 'TransformedItem' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'NestedItem'.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know whether or not `Item` will have a `children` property. Generally speaking, TypeScript object types are extendible/open and not exact/closed (as in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)); if a property is not mentioned in the definition of an object type, it *doesn't* mean a value of that type will lack a property at that key; it means the compiler doesn't know what, if anything, will be at that key.  Since the type declaration for `Item` doesn't mention a specific type for the `children` property, the compiler treats it as possibly existing, with a type of `unknown` or `any`, and any access of that property is treated as an error.

The union `Item | NestedItem` therefore has the same problem; because it might be an `Item` and we can't just access `children` on it.

---

One way to address this is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `Item` so that if it does have a `children` property it will be `undefined`:

```
function buildTree<
    Item extends { children?: undefined }, 
    TransformedItem extends NestedItem
>(
    data: Item[],
    transform: (item: Item) => TransformedItem | Item = item => item
) {
    const result = []
    for (const item of data) {
        const transformedItem = transform({ ...item })
        const resultItem = Object.assign({}, transformedItem, {
            children: transformedItem.children || [] // no error
        })
        result.push(resultItem)
    }    
    return result
}
```

This fixes the problem in the implementation, although it might be harder to call `buildTree()` since you'd then have to guarantee that the `data` elements necessarily lack a `children` property... which, as I mentioned, is not how it works:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
}
const foos: Foo[] = [{ a: "A" }, { a: "B" }];    
buildTree(foos, x => x) // error!
// -----> ~~~~
//  type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to type '{ children?: undefined; }[]
```

That error happens because the compiler can't guarantee that a `Foo` has no `children` property.  It's technically the truth:

```
const hmm = { a: "C", children: "no thanks" };
foos.push(hmm);
```

So this version gives you maximum type safety but at the expense of convenience.

---

If you're not worried about the possibility that `data`'s elements might have some `children` properties, then you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation of `buildTree()` to tell the compiler that `transformedItem`'s `children` property is either missing or a `NestedItem`:

```
function buildTree<Item, TransformedItem extends NestedItem>(
    data: Item[],
    transform: (item: Item) => TransformedItem | Item = item => item
) {
    const result = []
    for (const item of data) {
        const transformedItem = transform({ ...item })
        const resultItem = Object.assign({}, transformedItem, {
            children: (transformedItem as TransformedItem | 
                { children?: never }).children || []
        })
        result.push(resultItem)
    }

    return result
}
```

And so you won't get an error if you call `buildTree()` on a `Foo[]`:

```
const works = buildTree(foos, x => x); // okay
```

But do be aware that if you do have an unexpected `children` property inside the array element, it can lead to uncaught errors at runtime because you've lied to the compiler:

```
for (const w of works) {
    console.log(w.children.join(",")); 
    // "", "", and then  RUNTIME ERROR! w.children.join is not a function
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCYElIC2yA3gFDIXIIAWwANtlBCAPwBcamO+EBA2gF1SAX1KkYAVxAIwwAPYhkAIwn1sAFSYQAPDyIQAHpBDYMJKrQZNWHKdggxQEbMmEAaZJrggMMOVAJnPWRDY1NOLCDCAD4ACnJKbDgwOA49QTcEijAob19-Ag5Y4EI0wgBKZABeaM9cnz8AqN5kAB9kYKrkEpaa7sJSSrJKKgUsZCYMCTowauRBLORG5FiEMdmeojkYZCSUocWRtZ9ZnLzGwLxCObOGgtjiZAA6F83XcsPKY-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-grAl47IIlD6CV8YxyH2Tx0HIsKxGB7n4swTwgnIoCxKeNrlF+yCpjap6XpNgC8G4ApTvIAASgAqqg6i4AAsgAosgm0LQtgILYmNVdRSIC9f1ijAK27YuksUgyPIIAiEAA)